# Transistor simulation not working properly in Proteus

Tags: transistors, schematics, simulation, proteus, software

I'm recently working with Proteus. So I created a simple schematic for a transistor to work as a switch. But when I simulate it, it doesn't work as it should. In the picture below you can see that the resistor is not receiving current at the base, however the led is lighted up as if it were. I've even tried to remove everything from the base of the transistor and even then somehow the led still lights up. So I suppose it's a problem with the software. But maybe there's a setting missconfigured that I don't know of. Have anyone had this problem or any idea on what could be a solution? Thanks.

PD. I've already tried to reinstall the software and it didn't work.

[image: Simulation running in Proteus]

Comment: Try a pull down resistor on the base to ground.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but that was not the problem. I fixed it changing the "model type" of the led from "digital" to "analog".

Comment: A good news story.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. First I switched the "model type" of the Led from "digital" to "analog". Then I changed the transistor to a 2N2222. And I also fixed a design problem by adding a resistor that goes from the base to ground, to avoid any charge in the environment from turning on the transistor.

[image]